# How to get the id of iframe

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById(Iframe_id).contentWindow.addEventListener("blur", blurtest, true);
```

By using this line I have given the blur event to iframe. it is working.

But When in

```
function blurtest(e)
{
    alert(e.target.id); 
}
```

alert is used, but it gives value as Undefined.In other events it is working. So How to get the id of iframe in this blur function?.

Comment: You need to add a name attribute to the iframe,have you done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 ways, to use scope closures to remember the variable during set up:

```
var theID = Iframe_id;
document.getElementById(Iframe_id).contentWindow.addEventListener("blur", function( ){ blurtest( theID ), true);
```

or using a proper way to get the source element of an event

```
function blurtest( e )
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var obj = e.srcElement ? e.srcElement : e.target;
    alert( obj.getAttribute( 'id' ) );
}
```

good luck!

Comment: then give it an up click for me, :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the automatic variable `this`. It should contain the element on which the event was fired.

Answer (score 0):

When you load page into iFrmae,  put into  id of that iframe. So you can get the ID out of i by "this.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].id;"